# Remove the repeated entry in the bibliography

Tags: biblatex

In my edition of a Sanskrit text I use the abbreviation of the sources instead of "author-year". Following some suggestions found only I got the format I want, but I need to remove or hide the repeated abbreviation, i.e., in the following example, I need to remove the second HBṬ and PV in the list. Sincerely thanks to any suggestion.

**MWE**:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setotherlanguage{sanskrit}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{bibresource-test.bib}

\usepackage[noend, nopenalties, nofamiliar, noeledsec, noledgroup, series={A,B}]{reledmac}

\Xarrangement[A,B]{paragraph}  
\Xlemmaseparator[A]{{} \textbf{---}} 
\Xlemmaseparator[B]{{} \textbf{:}}  
\Xparafootsep{ $\diamond$ }
\lineation{page}
\firstlinenum{1}
\linenumincrement{1}

\Xnotenumfont{\sffamily}

\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{0}
%\setstanzaindents{1,1}
\setstanzaindents{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\makeatletter
%\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.5\baselineskip plus 0.5\baselineskip}

\newsavebox\ay@labelbox
\newlength{\labwidthsameline}
\setlength{\labwidthsameline}{3em}

\newbibmacro{labelwidthbib}{%
  \begingroup
  \DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperref}{##1}%
  \csuse{blx@hook@cite}%
  \csuse{blx@hook@citekey}%
  \global\undef\cbx@lasthash
  \global\undef\cbx@lastyear
  \citetrackerfalse\pagetrackerfalse\backtrackerfalse
  \defcounter{maxnames}{\blx@maxcitenames}%
%  \printtext[brackets]{\usebibmacro{cite}}%
  \printtext{\usebibmacro{cite}}%
  \endgroup
} 
%-----------------------
\newbibmacro{kicklabel}{% 
  \sbox\ay@labelbox{\usebibmacro{labelwidthbib}}%
  \global\togglefalse{blx@insert}%
  \ifdim\wd\ay@labelbox>\labwidthsameline
    \leavevmode\newline
  \fi
}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}%
  {\list
    {\usebibmacro{labelwidthbib}}%
    {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labwidthsameline}%
     \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
     \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
     \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
     \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
     \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
     \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}}%
      {\endlist}%
      {\item\usebibmacro{kicklabel}}
\makeatother

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\begin{document}
\Xmaxhnotes{.33\textheight}
\linenummargin{inner}
\beginnumbering \vspace{1cm}

\stanza
\edtext{bhāgā eva hi bhāsante sanniviṣṭās tathā tathā |& 
tadvān anyaḥ punar naiva nirbhāgaḥ pratibhāsate ||}{\lemma{bhāgā\dots\ pratibhāsate}\Afootnote{\cite{HBṬ} 29,32 (p. 106.25--26)}}

\edtext{vicāraprastuter eva prasiddhaḥ. siddha āśrayaḥ |& 
svecchākalpitabhedeṣu yadārtheṣv avivādataḥ ||}{\lemma{vicāraprastuter\dots\ avivādataḥ}\Afootnote{\cite{PV} 4.77}}\&

\pstart avayavānāṃ dharmitve vyatiriktaṃ paṭādidravyam ekam anirākṛtaṃ syād iti cet. nanv avayavavyaktiriktaṃ nāparaṃ paṭādidravyam upalabhyate. ...\pend 

\endnumbering

\section*{\centering Bibliography}
\subsection*{Primary Sources}
\printbibliography[title=none,keyword=pri,heading=none]
\subsection*{Secondary Sources}
\printbibliography[title=none,keyword=sec,heading=none]

\end{document}
```

And the **bibresource**:

```
@misc{HBṬ,
  entrysubtype = {classical},
  title = {HBṬ },
  note = {Hetubinduṭīkā (Arcaṭa)},
  related = {Sanghavi-Jinavijayaji1949},
  keywords = {pri}
  }

@misc{PV,
  entrysubtype = {classical},
  title = {PV },
  note = {Pramāṇavārttikakārikā (Dharmakīrti), see \cite{Miyasaka1971}},
  related = {},
  keywords = {pri}
}

@book{Miyasaka1971,
editor = {Yūsho Miyasaka},
date = {1971/1972},
title = {Pramāṇa­varttika-Kārikā (Sanskrit and Tibetan)},
%series = {Acta Indologica 2},
volumes = {2},
%publisher = {Naritasan Shishoji},
address = {Naritasan Shinshoji},
keywords = {sec}
}

@book{Sanghavi-Jinavijayaji1949,
editor = {Sukhlalji Sanghavi and Muni Shri Jinavijayaji},
title = {Hetubinduṭīkā of Bhaṭṭa Arcaṭa with the Sub-Commentary Entitled Āloka of Durveka Miśra},
volume = {},
address = {Baroda},
year = {1949},
keywords = {sec}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please format your LaTeX correctly, using the tools from this site so that it's easier to read. Also, make sure it's a Minimal Working Example, i.e. remove everything that isn't necessary to study your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you want correctly, I'd suggest you use the `shorthand` field for the abbreviations (*HBṬ* and *PV*). `biblatex-chicago`'s `authordate` behaviour is a bit odd when it comes to `shorthands`, so I recommend you use the option `cmslos=false,` to get back to a more normal `shorthand` behaviour.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setotherlanguage{sanskrit}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber, cmslos=false]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage[noend, nopenalties, nofamiliar, noeledsec, noledgroup, series={A,B}]{reledmac}

\Xarrangement[A,B]{paragraph}  
\Xlemmaseparator[A]{{} \textbf{---}} 
\Xlemmaseparator[B]{{} \textbf{:}}  
\Xparafootsep{ $\diamond$ }
\lineation{page}
\firstlinenum{1}
\linenumincrement{1}

\Xnotenumfont{\sffamily}

\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{0}
%\setstanzaindents{1,1}
\setstanzaindents{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\makeatletter
%\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.5\baselineskip plus 0.5\baselineskip}

\newsavebox\ay@labelbox
\newlength{\labwidthsameline}
\setlength{\labwidthsameline}{3em}

\newbibmacro{labelwidthbib}{%
  \begingroup
  \DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperref}{##1}%
  \csuse{blx@hook@cite}%
  \csuse{blx@hook@citekey}%
  \global\undef\cbx@lasthash
  \global\undef\cbx@lastyear
  \citetrackerfalse\pagetrackerfalse\backtrackerfalse
  \defcounter{maxnames}{\blx@maxcitenames}%
  \usebibmacro{cite}%
  \endgroup
} 
%-----------------------
\newbibmacro{kicklabel}{% 
  \sbox\ay@labelbox{\usebibmacro{labelwidthbib}}%
  \global\togglefalse{blx@insert}%
  \ifdim\wd\ay@labelbox>\labwidthsameline
    \leavevmode\newline
  \fi
}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}%
  {\list
    {\usebibmacro{labelwidthbib}}%
    {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labwidthsameline}%
     \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
     \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
     \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
     \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
     \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
     \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}}%
      {\endlist}%
      {\item\usebibmacro{kicklabel}}
\makeatother

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{HBṬ,
  entrysubtype = {classical},
  shorthand    = {HBṬ},
  title        = {Hetubinduṭīkā (Arcaṭa)},
  related      = {Sanghavi-Jinavijayaji1949},
  keywords     = {pri},
}
@misc{PV,
  entrysubtype = {classical},
  shorthand    = {PV},
  title        = {Pramāṇavārttikakārikā (Dharmakīrti), see \cite{Miyasaka1971}},
  related      = {},
  keywords     = {pri},
}
@book{Miyasaka1971,
  editor     = {Yūsho Miyasaka},
  date       = {1971/1972},
  title      = {Pramāṇa­varttika-Kārikā (Sanskrit and Tibetan)},
  %series    = {Acta Indologica 2},
  volumes    = {2},
  %publisher = {Naritasan Shishoji},
  address    = {Naritasan Shinshoji},
  keywords   = {sec},
}
@book{Sanghavi-Jinavijayaji1949,
  editor   = {Sukhlalji Sanghavi and Muni Shri Jinavijayaji},
  title    = {Hetubinduṭīkā of Bhaṭṭa Arcaṭa with the Sub-Commentary Entitled Āloka of Durveka Miśra},
  volume   = {},
  address  = {Baroda},
  year     = {1949},
  keywords = {sec},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\Xmaxhnotes{.33\textheight}
\linenummargin{inner}
\beginnumbering \vspace{1cm}

\stanza
\edtext{bhāgā eva hi bhāsante sanniviṣṭās tathā tathā |& 
tadvān anyaḥ punar naiva nirbhāgaḥ pratibhāsate ||}{\lemma{bhāgā\dots\ pratibhāsate}\Afootnote{\cite{HBṬ} 29,32 (p. 106.25--26)}}

\edtext{vicāraprastuter eva prasiddhaḥ. siddha āśrayaḥ |& 
svecchākalpitabhedeṣu yadārtheṣv avivādataḥ ||}{\lemma{vicāraprastuter\dots\ avivādataḥ}\Afootnote{\cite{PV} 4.77}}\&

\pstart avayavānāṃ dharmitve vyatiriktaṃ paṭādidravyam ekam anirākṛtaṃ syād iti cet. nanv avayavavyaktiriktaṃ nāparaṃ paṭādidravyam upalabhyate. ...\pend 

\endnumbering

\section*{\centering Bibliography}
\subsection*{Primary Sources}
\printbibliography[title=none,keyword=pri,heading=none]
\subsection*{Secondary Sources}
\printbibliography[title=none,keyword=sec,heading=none]

\end{document}
```

[image: HBṬ Hetubinduṭīkā (Arcaṭa), Sukhlalji Sanghavi and Muni Shri Jinavijayaji, eds., Hetubinduṭīkā of Bhaṭṭa Arcaṭa with the Sub-Commentary Entitled Āloka of Durveka Miśra, Baroda, 1949. PV Pramāṇavārttikakārikā (Dharmakīrti), see Miyasaka 1971–72.]

Comment: @SumatiBhadra You can accept the answer by clicking on the green checkmark on the top left of the answer (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235, https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer and https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). A comment is not necessary.