# How to move "year" to the end of the entry in bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, biber, biblatex-chicago

I use `authordate` style of `biblatex-chicago` package for two groups of sources, the `Primary Sources` and `Secondary Sources`. The main problem has been solved (see [Remove the repeated entry in the bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/644940/remove-the-repeated-entry-in-the-bibliography)). What I want now is to move the publishing year(s) in the Secondary Sources to the end of the entry, just like it is in the Primary Sources; more precisely, in the example linked above, I want to move "1971-72" to the end, i.e., change

> Miyasaka, YŪsho, ed., 1971-72, Pramāṇa­varttika-Kārikā (Sanskrit and Tibetan), 2 vols., Naritasan Shinshoji

to

> Miyasaka, YŪsho, ed., Pramāṇa­varttika-Kārikā (Sanskrit and Tibetan), 2 vols., Naritasan Shinshoji, 1971-72.

For the convenience of readers, I paste MWE here:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setotherlanguage{sanskrit}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber, cmslos=false]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage[noend, nopenalties, nofamiliar, noeledsec, noledgroup, series={A,B}]{reledmac}

\Xarrangement[A,B]{paragraph}  
\Xlemmaseparator[A]{{} \textbf{---}} 
\Xlemmaseparator[B]{{} \textbf{:}}  
\Xparafootsep{ $\diamond$ }
\lineation{page}
\firstlinenum{1}
\linenumincrement{1}

\Xnotenumfont{\sffamily}

\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{0}
\setstanzaindents{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox\ay@labelbox
\newlength{\labwidthsameline}
\setlength{\labwidthsameline}{3em}

\newbibmacro{labelwidthbib}{%
  \begingroup
  \DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperref}{##1}%
  \csuse{blx@hook@cite}%
  \csuse{blx@hook@citekey}%
  \global\undef\cbx@lasthash
  \global\undef\cbx@lastyear
  \citetrackerfalse\pagetrackerfalse\backtrackerfalse
  \defcounter{maxnames}{\blx@maxcitenames}%
  \usebibmacro{cite}%
  \endgroup
} 
%-----------------------
\newbibmacro{kicklabel}{% 
  \sbox\ay@labelbox{\usebibmacro{labelwidthbib}}%
  \global\togglefalse{blx@insert}%
  \ifdim\wd\ay@labelbox>\labwidthsameline
    \leavevmode\newline
  \fi
}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}%
  {\list
    {\usebibmacro{labelwidthbib}}%
    {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labwidthsameline}%
     \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
     \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
     \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
     \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
     \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
     \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}}%
      {\endlist}%
      {\item\usebibmacro{kicklabel}}
\makeatother

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{HBṬ,
  entrysubtype = {classical},
  shorthand    = {HBṬ},
  title        = {Hetubinduṭīkā (Arcaṭa)},
  related      = {Sanghavi-Jinavijayaji1949},
  keywords     = {pri},
}
@misc{PV,
  entrysubtype = {classical},
  shorthand    = {PV},
  title        = {Pramāṇavārttikakārikā (Dharmakīrti), see \cite{Miyasaka1971}},
  related      = {},
  keywords     = {pri},
}
@book{Miyasaka1971,
  editor     = {Yūsho Miyasaka},
  date       = {1971/1972},
  title      = {Pramāṇa­varttika-Kārikā (Sanskrit and Tibetan)},
  %series    = {Acta Indologica 2},
  volumes    = {2},
  %publisher = {Naritasan Shishoji},
  address    = {Naritasan Shinshoji},
  keywords   = {sec},
}
@book{Sanghavi-Jinavijayaji1949,
  editor   = {Sukhlalji Sanghavi and Muni Shri Jinavijayaji},
  title    = {Hetubinduṭīkā of Bhaṭṭa Arcaṭa with the Sub-Commentary Entitled Āloka of Durveka Miśra},
  volume   = {},
  address  = {Baroda},
  year     = {1949},
  keywords = {sec},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\Xmaxhnotes{.33\textheight}
\linenummargin{inner}
\beginnumbering \vspace{1cm}

\stanza
\edtext{bhāgā eva hi bhāsante sanniviṣṭās tathā tathā |& 
tadvān anyaḥ punar naiva nirbhāgaḥ pratibhāsate ||}{\lemma{bhāgā\dots\ pratibhāsate}\Afootnote{\cite{HBṬ} 29,32 (p. 106.25--26)}}

\edtext{vicāraprastuter eva prasiddhaḥ. siddha āśrayaḥ |& 
svecchākalpitabhedeṣu yadārtheṣv avivādataḥ ||}{\lemma{vicāraprastuter\dots\ avivādataḥ}\Afootnote{\cite{PV} 4.77}}\&

\pstart avayavānāṃ dharmitve vyatiriktaṃ paṭādidravyam ekam anirākṛtaṃ syād iti cet. nanv avayavavyaktiriktaṃ nāparaṃ paṭādidravyam upalabhyate. ...\pend 

\endnumbering

\section*{\centering Bibliography}
\subsection*{Primary Sources}
\printbibliography[title=none,keyword=pri,heading=none]
\subsection*{Secondary Sources}
\printbibliography[title=none,keyword=sec,heading=none]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`biblatex-chicago` is a very complex style, because it tries to implement the very complex rules of the Chicago Manual of Style as closely as possible. As such, modifications (even if they look like the 'should be simple') can be pretty difficult to pull. If you intend to deviate even further from Chicago style, I strongly suggest you look into using one of the `biblatex` standard styles. Unlike `biblatex-chocago` they were meant to be modified easily.

In this particular instance I think we can get the desired effect simply by redefining a single bibmacro

```
\renewbibmacro*{cmsbibsortdate}{}
```

Since `biblatex-chicago` is so complex, it is very possible that this change has side effects, so please check the output carefully.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setotherlanguage{sanskrit}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber, cmslos=false]{biblatex-chicago}

\makeatletter
\newsavebox\ay@labelbox
\newlength{\labwidthsameline}
\setlength{\labwidthsameline}{3em}

\newbibmacro{labelwidthbib}{%
  \begingroup
  \DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperref}{##1}%
  \csuse{blx@hook@cite}%
  \csuse{blx@hook@citekey}%
  \global\undef\cbx@lasthash
  \global\undef\cbx@lastyear
  \citetrackerfalse\pagetrackerfalse\backtrackerfalse
  \defcounter{maxnames}{\blx@maxcitenames}%
  \usebibmacro{cite}%
  \endgroup
} 
%-----------------------
\newbibmacro{kicklabel}{% 
  \sbox\ay@labelbox{\usebibmacro{labelwidthbib}}%
  \global\togglefalse{blx@insert}%
  \ifdim\wd\ay@labelbox>\labwidthsameline
    \leavevmode\newline
  \fi
}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}%
  {\list
    {\usebibmacro{labelwidthbib}}%
    {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labwidthsameline}%
     \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
     \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
     \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
     \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
     \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
     \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}}%
      {\endlist}%
      {\item\usebibmacro{kicklabel}}


\renewbibmacro*{cmsbibsortdate}{}
\makeatother

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{HBṬ,
  entrysubtype = {classical},
  shorthand    = {HBṬ},
  title        = {Hetubinduṭīkā (Arcaṭa)},
  related      = {Sanghavi-Jinavijayaji1949},
  keywords     = {pri},
}
@misc{PV,
  entrysubtype = {classical},
  shorthand    = {PV},
  title        = {Pramāṇavārttikakārikā (Dharmakīrti), see \cite{Miyasaka1971}},
  related      = {},
  keywords     = {pri},
}
@book{Miyasaka1971,
  editor     = {Yūsho Miyasaka},
  date       = {1971/1972},
  title      = {Pramāṇa­varttika-Kārikā (Sanskrit and Tibetan)},
  %series    = {Acta Indologica 2},
  volumes    = {2},
  %publisher = {Naritasan Shishoji},
  address    = {Naritasan Shinshoji},
  keywords   = {sec},
}
@book{Sanghavi-Jinavijayaji1949,
  editor   = {Sukhlalji Sanghavi and Muni Shri Jinavijayaji},
  title    = {Hetubinduṭīkā of Bhaṭṭa Arcaṭa with the Sub-Commentary Entitled Āloka of Durveka Miśra},
  volume   = {},
  address  = {Baroda},
  year     = {1949},
  keywords = {sec},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{HBṬ,PV}

\section*{\centering Bibliography}
\subsection*{Primary Sources}
\printbibliography[keyword=pri, heading=none]
\subsection*{Secondary Sources}
\printbibliography[keyword=sec, heading=none]
\end{document}
```

[image: Miyasaka, Yūsho, ed., Pramāṇavarttika-Kārikā (Sanskrit and Tibetan), 2 vols., Naritasan Shinshoji, 1971–72.]

Comment: I accept your suggestion, it works perfectly!